# Regex to find immediate duplicate tag

Tags: regex, notepad++

I am using Notepad++, wherein I have to find and remove the immediate duplicate HTML tag which is shown below

**Actual**

```
<a href="www.google.com"><a href="www.google.com">www.google.com</a></a>
```

**Required**

```
<a href="www.google.com">www.google.com</a>
```

I have a regex to find duplicates which comes in new line, but my search will be with in a line.

Pl help me

Comment: Somebody had to do it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: Do you search only links twice nested?

Comment: @squiguy the OP isn't parsing HTML, simply trying to match a pattern in a text file for replacement in the program.

Comment: @AbsoluteƵERØ - You are right but you have to admit that after all this time, it's still so much fun to read <g>.

Answer (score 2):

**Find:**

`(<(\w+)(\s[^>]*)?>)\1(.*)(<\/\2>)\5`

**Replace**:

`\1\4\5`

Tested in Sublime.

Comment: @AbsoluteƵERØ Thanks for testing it out in ++

Answer (score 1):

For this kind of "double links" you can use this:

```
find: <(a [^>]+)>(<\1>.*?</a>)</a>
replace: \2
```

For all tags use:

```
find: <((\w+)[^>]*)>(<\1>.*?</\2>)</\2>
replace: \3
```

(the two with a recent version of notepad++)

Answer (score 1):

Search Pattern:

```
.*">(<.*>)<\/a>
```

Replace:

```
\1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this pattern

```
(<(\w+)(\s[^>]*)?>)(\s|\n|\t)*\1(.*)(<\/\2>)(\s|\n|\t)*\6
```

Demo:http://rubular.com/r/RT7ObfV0i8

replace \1 and \6

Comment: This doesn't keep the data between the tags in Notepad++. It does get rid of the duplicate tag though. Should say replace \1\5\6.